# Thymeleaf: convert a comma double to a dot double

Tags: html, thymeleaf

i have the following code:

```
  <td><input type="number" step="0.00000001" th:value="${product.getNumber()}" name="number"/></td>
```

`getNumber` returns an ordinary double like `1.0E-8`

My issues are:

1. I want that it doesn't show 1.0E-8 instead it should present 0.00000001.
2. Moreover numbers like 0.0001 are represented with a comma like 0,0001

I tried to work with that http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.15/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html but had no success.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `#numbers` utility from Thymeleaf ([API](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html#formatDecimal-java.lang.Number-java.lang.Integer-java.lang.Integer-)) and set the digits accordingly.

```
th:value="${#numbers.formatDecimal(product.number, 2, 3)}"
```

This sets minimum integer digits (2 in the above) and exact decimal digits (3 in the above).

For the separator, you can specify it directly:

```
th:value="${#numbers.formatDecimal(product.number, 2, 3,'COMMA')}"
```

The separator options are `POINT`, `COMMA`, `WHITESPACE`, `NONE` or `DEFAULT` (by locale).

Bear in mind that the browser may employ different rules and you may wish to use `step="any"` in certain cases.  (For printing directly using `th:text`, this will not matter.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class CommonUtil {
    public static final String DOT = ".";

    public static String comma(BigDecimal n) {
        return comma(String.valueOf(n));
    }

    public static String comma(double n) {
        return comma(String.valueOf(n));
    }

    public static String comma(String n) {
        try {
            List<String> h = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(n, CommonUtil.DOT));
            String decimal = h.size() == 2 ?
                "." + h.get(1) :
                "";

            return comma(Integer.parseInt(h.get(0))) + decimal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("NaN <{}>", n);
            return n;
        }
    }

    public static String comma(int n) {
        return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(n);
    }
}
```